# Issues with getting multiple site id in django

Tags: python, django, templates, mezzanine, multiple-sites

I am using two domain names(.com and .mx) for a mezzanine project.When I am using the **Site.objects.get_current()** function for getting the current site id It return only one **1**.
whether I used .com OR .mx in my browser.

I think it is because in my settings.py the **SITE_ID = 1**  defined and when I edit it to 2 then **Site.objects.get_current()**  function returns 2.

But what I actually wants is to define the **templates by site**  , that is when user use .com then he will see **a.html** and when he use .mx he will see **b.html**.But as I told **Site.objects.get_current()** function gives me only one id whether I used .com or .mx  , so I can't define the template by site.

So please suggest me some way to get dynamic site id  or there is another way with which I can define template by site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly how the Sites framework works. To differentiate between sites using the sites framework, every site must have its own settings module (because that's where you set the `SITE_ID`).

What you are looking for is a way to get the current site from the request. You could use the [`RequestSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects) object for this:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite    
site_name = RequestSite(request).domain
```

There's also [django-dynamicsites](https://bitbucket.org/uysrc/django-dynamicsites/) which does the same thing with a few more extras (redirects, template/url assignment, ...)

Comment: Mezzanine implements dynamic site loading, which forgoes the use of SITE_ID, so this answer is somewhat misleading.


Have a look at the docs around this: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html#multiple-sites-and-multi-tenancy

Comment: Also take a look at `mezzanine.utils.sites.current_site_id` which provides access to the site ID currently being accessed.